# How do I find all elements with a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of elements on my page that have a `lang` attribute.  How do I select only the elements with a `lang` attribute?

i.e.

```
<div lang="english">Test</div>
<span lang="english">is cool</span>
<span lang="anotherlanguage">is also good</span>
```

Comment: there even is a predefined css-selector for this ;)  see: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Comment: Wow, I never knew that! I tweaked my actual code to `hasTranslation` rather than `lang` as I'm using it to allow my page to translate specific words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxjx2/1/)**

```
var res = $('[lang=english]')
```

You can iterate through each item use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('[lang=english]').each(function () {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: But do try and put all relevant elements within a predictable parent element (not necessarily the *same* element), just to avoid having to look at *every* element in the DOM.

Comment: Oh, and bear in mind he didn't necessarily want only those elements with `lang` attribute equal to `"english"`, but all that have the attribute.

Comment: @DavidThomas exactly, thankfully the poster gave me enough to go on to fix the problem

Comment: @Chris: depending on what you're doing you also may not need to use the `each()` method, you might be able to use an anonymous function within another method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('*[lang]').each(function () {
   //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via HTML5 data-* attribute. Set the attribute like this

```
 ``
```

To fetch all elements with data-lang set to "english" use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-lang="english"]');
```

Comment: Yes, you could do it with a HTML5 `data-*` attribute, but I don't see why you would when there's already an existing `lang` attribute.

Comment: looks like the editor stripped off the html this is how you have to set the attribute 
<pre>
<div data-lang="english">
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

While you already have an (accepted) answer to this question, I thought I'd post an additional answer, to more completely answer the question as asked, also to cover the various issues I've raised in comments to those other answers.

Each approach I discuss in my answer will be applied to the following HTML mark-up:

```
<div class="langContainer">
    <span lang="english">Some text in an English span</span>
    <span lang="french">Some text in an French span</span>
    <span lang="algerian">Some text in an Algerian span</span>
    <span lang="urdu">Some text in an Urdu span</span>
</div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<ol>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two</li>
    <li>List item three</li>
    <li>List item four</li>
    <li>List item five</li>
    <li>List item six</li>
    <li>List item seven</li>
</ol>

<ul class="langContainer">
    <li><div lang="english">Some text in an English div</div></li>
    <li><div lang="french">Some text in an French div</div></li>
    <li><div lang="algerian">Some text in an Algerian div</div></li>
    <li><div lang="urdu">Some text in an Urdu div</div></li>
</ul>
```

The easiest way to style elements with a `lang` attribute is CSS, for example:

```
:lang(english),
:lang(french) {
    color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/1/).

The above will style *all* elements with a `lang` attribute equal to `english` or `french`. Of course, this being CSS, it's possible to modify the selector to apply to only specific elements with those attributes:

```
span:lang(english),
div:lang(french) {
    color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/2/).

This, as you would imagine, styles a `span` with a `lang` attribute equal to `english` and a `div` element with a `lang` attribute equal to `french`.

Using the `:lang()` pseudo-class, without passing a value, does *not*, unfortunately, select elements that simply possess a `lang` attribute.

However, using the CSS attribute-selector `[lang]` does:

```
[lang] {
    color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/3/).

The absence of an element in that selector, of course, implies the universal selector so to select more *accurately* it might be wise to modify the selector to apply to either specific element-types ([`span[lang]`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/4/)) or to elements within a specific parent element ([`div.langContainer [lang]`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/5/)).

However, for other purposes, such as modifying the content, or element-nodes themselves, using jQuery you have the same selectors available, for example.

In the following examples I'll be assigning the element's original text to jQuery's `data` object (with the variable-name of `original-text`) and replacing the element's visible text (as a demonstration of passing an anonymous function to a method, to avoid having to iterate through the matched elements with `each()`, though you can do that if you want to), with that in mind I'll post only the selector:

```
// selecting elements with lang equal to 'english':
$(':lang(english)')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/6/).

```
// selecting all elements with the lang attribute:
$('[lang]')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/8/).

```
// specifying the element-type:
$('span[lang]')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/7/).

```
// specifying the element-type:
$('div.langContainer [lang]')
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/9/).

It seems, incidentally, from a [jsPerf comparison of the jQuery approaches](http://jsperf.com/comparison-of-selector-approaches), that defining the element type (for example `$('span[lang]')`) is the fastest means by which to select (that said, of course, if you're only *styling* the content then CSS would be faster yet).

A brief discussion of using `each()` versus an anonymous function passed to a method.

Using this approach depends entirely on what you want to do, but if you want to, for example, modify the text of each matched-element, the two following approaches are equivalent:

```
$('span[lang]').each(function(i){
    $(this).text('matched element ' + i);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/10/);

```
$('span[lang]').text(function(i) { return 'matched element ' + i; });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLqmS/11/);

There is, however, no significant difference between the time it takes to run either.

Comment: Hi David. Thankyou for the very comprehensive answer (and comments) +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[lang="english"],[lang="anotherlanguage"]')
```